# Using Scripts in Reference Db Project

Tags: sql-server, database-project

I have a base Sql Db project (ProjectA) that contains common table definitions, and a script which sets up triggers on those tables

I then have another Db project (ProjectB) that references ProjectA.

I would like to somehow reference the script stored in ProjectA from ProjectB, ideally executing it during the postdeploy script I have in ProjectB.

Is this possible?

EDIT: The reference to ProjectA is as a .dacpac, not a .sqlproj.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..\` paths in your post-deployment script to reference files outside of the database project.

```
-- this script is in the same folder as the post-deploy script
:r ".\script1.sql"

-- this script is in the project's parent directory
:r "..\..\..\script2.sql"
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - ProjectB refers to ProjectA as a .dacpac, not a .sqlproj - so I don't actually have the script .sql file on my file system at other, other than as an item inside the .dacpac